# How can I use a method of a object without using the object's variable name?

Tags: php, oop

I apologize if this question doesn't make a lot of sense; I'm having a little bit of trouble putting it into words. I'm still learning a lot about PHP and I don't have the vocabulary down quite yet.

I have a class that has a method that accepts a different class object as it's only parameter:

```
class myClass {
    protected $name;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function myMethod($string) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
$myObject = new myClass();
$myObject->myMethod($myObject->getName());
```

without using the variable name of the object's method that is being passed in to `myMethod()`. In my head, that would work something like this:

```
$myObject->myMethod($this->getName());
```

but it doesn't. Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Comment: But `$myObject->getName()` is not a class as in your prototype. Its a string

Comment: Are you talking about magic methods?

Comment: My mistake. I typed it out incorrectly. It's been changed. And I'm not familiar with magic methods, @brassxzero. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible because $this exists only withing the class and represents its object. If you have class Person and inside you have $this, that means it is a reference to current Person object. But if you have outside of any class, that represents nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot. You need to refer object variable explicitly.

You could make your proposition here https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto to force syntax changing.